# How to install Crystal Report without Visual Studio 2015 in Windows server 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Previously I installed crystal report with visual studio 2015, that crystal report version is 13.0.20..

Now I want to install crystal report another windows server 2012, but without visual 2015..

I am looking for the same version of crystal report, but without visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Crystal Report 13.0.20 without visual studio.
Just double click on exe file of Crystal Report 13.0.20 then you will get installation window. I hope will work. If you don't have Crystal Report 13.0.20 so download from here

```
http://www.crystalreports.com/crvs/confirm/
```

Comment: No I cannot install. it's popping up a window to install visual studio

Comment: Can I have your Crystal Report size?

Comment: 290 MB, file name is CRforVS_13_0_20

Comment: Okay then Download 13.0.20 version from this url. I think it will not require Visual studio https://www.tektutorialshub.com/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/

Comment: ok bro, I will try on your way and I will update you. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174580/discussion-between-noor-all-safaet-and-liam-neesan).